# What does this `%05i%` mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I saw this code getting random numbers. What does the `'%05i'%` do?

```
list = []
(list << '%05i' % (rand(99999)+1)).uniq! while list.length < 5
number1, number2, number3, number4, number5 = list
```

Comment: It formats the number as a fixed-width string representation; i.e. 1 would be printed as 00001 and 8999 would be printed as 08999.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it must demonstrate a minimum understanding

Answer (score 2):

`'%05i'` is a [format specification](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) where `0` means to pad with zeros, `5` means the width will be 5 characters, and `i` means the argument is a decimal number.  The `%` operator then [applies](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25) that format specification to the following argument (`(rand(99999)+1)` in this case).

`'%05i' % 1` evaluates to `"00001"`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat similar to `printf` in `C++`. It means construct a string using an integer padding it to 5 digits adding `0` on the left. `%i` is format specifier for integer. The 5 between the `%` and `i` means pad to 5 symbols and the `0` between the `%` and `5` means pad using `0`. After the string you write `%` and the value to use in the string. For example `'%05i' % 2'` will be `00002`.